# Envisage the Answer

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, language

Little bat went on a trip recently and met with four friends who were of different species. They wrote the following poem in his honor and, as an extra surprise, they hid inside it. Can you find them?

> Flitter, chitter little bat.
>   Won't you come and have a chat?
>   Long and short your squeaks, of course,
>   Code your thoughts - but not in Morse.
>   Puzzlers try with all their powers:
>   They can't crack this code of ours.
>   Fly! Or soon dawn's fiery fringe
>   May your fragile wing tips singe.

Hint:

> They met in a European country although the friends are not necessarily indigenous to Europe. To clarify, I am looking for the names of the species.

Comment: Do we need to find the bats name too?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil No. It is known simply as "Little Bat".

Comment: [This](http://ciphermysteries.com/2013/11/03/devils-handwriting-revisited) is what Google gave me...

Comment: Reminds me of [Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinkle,_Twinkle,_Little_Bat)

Comment: Sounds like it might be to do with rot13(rzbgvpbaf)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bat's four friends are ...

> ... a cat, a walrus, a bear and a monkey.

They met in ...

> ... France or a French-speaking country.

The friends can be found ...

> ... in the last words of each rhyming pair. The French words for the animals — *chat*, *morse*, *ours* and *singe* — look like the English words used in the poem, but they are pronounced differently.

Finally, the title ...

> ... hints at the French language with "envisage", which is of French origin.

Comment: And the answer is in your face, in a manner of speaking. Well done!

Comment: _Merci beaucoup_.

Comment: Let me convert 19999 to a nice number :) +1